# Not able to use LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, listagg

```
SELECT deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;
```

```
Error:- 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 42
```

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please be more elaborative about the error. When I execute the query on the 11g database, it is showing results without any errors

Comment: Most likely, the database version would not be 11g or higher version. `wm_concat` is the alternative for `LISTAGG`

Comment: I agree with @Jacob - which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: `listagg()` was introduced in 11.2 you can't use it in 11.1

Comment: wm_concat is also not working

Answer (score 0):

In [this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques) you have different approaches to dealing with string aggegation, including those to take into account if you are running an Oracle version prior to 11g Release 2 (which is your scenario).

Particularly, you can use Oracle's `WM_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT deptno, wm_concat(ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP BY deptno;
```

You can also define your own function for string aggregation or use other functions such as `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` or `COLLECT`. In the above article you have examples of these methods.